# What is an alternative to this rectifier? - GB14C40L

Tags: rectifier

We've nearly completed an engine swap on a car, which needs to have a piggy back ECU called an EMU to run the new engine.

The trouble is, the new ECU only sends a spark on two of the 6 cylinders. We opened it up, and found 4 out of the 6 rectifiers look burnt and cracked. A new ECU is around £800.

The part number for them is: GB14C40L 327P

I can find the parts on an online wholesale site, but am trying to find them locally.

Is there any alternative to this part we could look at using?

Comment: Believe it or not, SE.EE is not a purchase recommendation site because there is no EE content in this sort of Q and A.

Comment: @Andyaka You missed the point, I'm not looking for a purchase recommendation as such. I'm looking for another component that can function the same as this one.

Comment: You can't get the part today. You want it today. It's a purchase recommendation.

Comment: @Andyaka I can't get the part at all. I'm looking for a part which will function the same as this.

Comment: The trouble is you have no idea what parts are really dead. Some of the casualties may be obvious (burn marks, cracking, etc.), but usually that just means they were the part that gave in first. There can be other parts in the circuit that are damaged or the actual cause of the failure, so just replacing one part could quite easily result in burning the new transistors. If the ECU was bought new, I suggest you return it and get a new one.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that the part is still in production and pretty easy to get hold of, a couple of minutes spend checking on electronic component distribution websites would have revealed that Digikey have 3000+ in stock, Newark have 2000+, Farnell have 900+, and Mouser have 980.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Thanks but I did check those but they didn't have the same part number.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I have a pretty good idea that those are dead. I've tested that the components get the ignition signal on the gate, just nothing comes out the emitter on 4 / 6 . The ECU is actually a glorified arduino anyway.

Comment: The IRGB14C40L is the same part as you have. Sometimes for long part numbers manufacturers shorten what then print on the device. The 327P bit is the "Date Code" which stands for "YWWx". So 327P = "2013, 27th Week, Lead Free" according to the datasheet.

Answer (score 3):

The part is not a 'rectifier', it is a special internally clamped [IGBT](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irgb14c40lpbf.pdf) designed for coil-on-plug ignition systems. Maybe the IR logo misled you.

You've buggered them up, get the bicycle or whatever out until the proper parts arrive- this is not a time to add to the issues by trying to make do.

Comment: Didn't bugger them up. Bought it like that. It's not on my car either, it's on a project car. Googling the part number is what led me to think they were rectifiers, but seems like there are duplicate part numbers in the same package.